# Java Math.random closed double interval

Tags: java, random

How do I generate random double values in a closed interval [x;y] in Java, e.g  [0;10]? The API of `Math.random()` says it returns values in [0;1), so multiplying by 10 does not help (as well as multiplying by 11).

Comment: does it matter...the changes of hitting a 10 are very very very small

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:** I've looked into it further.

To get the next higher possible double value in magnitude, use `Math.ulp(double)`.

```
double number = 10.0 + Math.ulp(10.0);
```

The next higher value for `10.0` is `10.000000000000002`

In case of the random number generation:

```
double randomNumber = Math.random() * (10.0 + Math.ulp(10.0));
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ulp(double)

---

### My old theory which is not true:

`2e-1074` is the smallest positive nonzero value of type double.
The constant for this is `Double.MIN_VALUE`. So multiplying `10 + 2e-1074` with `Math.random()` should in theory give you a random number in the range [0;10]

```
double randomNumber = Math.random() * (10.0 + Double.MIN_VALUE);
```

Java docs for `Double.MIN_VALUE`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#MIN_VALUE

Comment: In my opinion this is the clearest and easiest answer to implement. If you go over your example, multiplying Math.random () by 10 will get the open range [0,10).
          [0,10) = [0.00000000000000000, 9.999999999999999]
The only difference is that there is no double number with a value of 10,000 ..... 0. Multiplying Math.random () with (10.0 + Double.MIN_VALUE) will solve the problem.

Comment: I don't think that this theory is correct. Even if 1 - `Double.MIN_VALUE`  is the greatest number of `Math.random()`, it would be too less to add `Double.MIN_VALUE` to the factor. The value we are looking for to add to the 10 is (10-10*x)/x, where x is the maximum of `Math.random()`.

Comment: As it stands, I don't think this is correct. Something + Double.MIN_VALUE == Something, for Something not too near zero, since Double.MIN_VALUE is less than the floating point epsilon, which is on the order of 1e-16.

Answer (score 3):

Very interesting question. I can think of two approaches to try. (1) Double floats are actually integers scaled by an exponent. How many distinct double float values are there in [0, 10]? You can generate an integer in [0, 1, 2, ... n] where n is that number, and then scale it to get a float. As an added wrinkle, there are different granularities of floats in different ranges. I suspect that you'll have to look at ranges of the form [2^m, 2^(m + 1)].

(2) Rejection method. Figure out a way to generate numbers in some range greater than [0, 10], then just reject any which don't fall in that range.

Good luck and have fun.

Comment: To (2) I thought of this before, but I don’t like that style.
To (1) I think that is the same idea of finding the largest number  `Math.random()` can return. It sounds promising, thanks for the inspiration!